# .cer and private key

Tags: certificate, private

I imported a .cer that was given to me by a vendor into the local machine (Trusted root to be specific). I was told the private key is inside. I opened up the cert using some .Net code and it is reporting the cert has no private key. Have I done something wrong? I always thought private cert must be imported through a .pfx file. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

.cer and .crt files are DER-encoded X509 certificates and cannot contain private keys.